# Запрос по последней дате в Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Наверное простейший запрос, нужно выбрать из таблицы данные, только по последней дате для [Код заявки].

SELECT Comment.[Код заявки], Comment.com, Max(Comment.date_com) AS [Max-date_com]
FROM Comment
GROUP BY Comment.[Код заявки], Comment.com;

Что я делаю не так? Выводит точно не только по последней дате.
И еще, в один день может быть несколько записей, как вывести только одну, последнюю?

Comment: Нужно как-то так SELECT Comment.[Код заявки], Comment.com, Comment.date_com AS [Max-date_com] WHERE date_com =max(date_com) FROM Comment GROUP BY Comment.[Код заявки], Comment.com;
но это не точно.

Comment: @Евгений если вам нужно получить последний текст комментария для каждой заявки: сначала получите последнюю дату для каждой заявки - потом сделайте join по номеру заявки и дате таблицы с собой же, пока у вас выводится последняя дата для каждого комментария к заявке

Comment: Как получить именно последнюю дату? У меня выбирает несколько дат, в том то и проблема.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka по вашему запросу ругается, что - Невозможно использование агрегатной функции в предложении WHERE date_com =max(date_com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

текст запроса:

```
SELECT Comment.[Код заявки], Comment.com,  Comment.date_com
FROM (SELECT
    [Код заявки]
    ,Max(date_com) AS lastdate
  FROM Comment
  GROUP BY [Код заявки]
 ) AS lastc
INNER JOIN Comment ON Comment.[Код заявки] = lastc.[Код заявки] and Comment.date_com = lastc.lastdate
```

Comment: Что то у меня ругается на отсутствие оператора. А последовательность та?

Comment: Кажется Access требует использование AS. Напишите вместо ) lastc => ) AS lastc

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko спасибо - добавил as

Comment: @Евгений подправил запрос - попробуйте сейчас

Comment: Браво, по дате отбирает! Теперь бы убрать убрать дубли по одной дате и супер!

Comment: *Теперь бы убрать убрать дубли по одной дате и супер!* Кроме последней даты и кода заявки в выводе присутствует поле Comment.com. Если оно для дублей идентично - спасёт DISTINCT (или группировка) во внешнем запросе (но тогда вопрос, какого лешего вообще в таблице дубликаты). А если не идентично - то попробуй группировку по остальным полям и, скажем, FIRST() этого поля.

Comment: @Евгений прочитайте внимательно еще раз ваш собственный вопрос и  найдите там требование про убирание дублей. Не нашли? И я не нашел, поэтому прошу добавить в ваш запрос дополнение, что вы считаете дублем и какой же результат вы хотите получить.

Comment: Дальше я разобрался, спасибо!